# Loop over listbuffer scala

Tags: scala

I'm new in scala language I have a listbuffer :

```
    var oldQuestions: Seq[Question] = section.questions
    var newQuestions: ListBuffer[Question] = new ListBuffer()
```

So all I need is,to loop over the newQuestions list and access to one question based on her id and delete it.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use vars, and mutable collections. It is a really, really rare occurrence that you actually need either of those in scala. So, for now, until you get  sufficient grip on the language to be able to tell when those rare cases happen, just pretend these things don't exist. Learn to write good functional code before you explore mutability.

To answer your question:

```
  val newQuestions: Seq[Question] = section.questions.filterNot(_.id == idToDelete)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm not familiar with scala, i'm trying to learn it and work on a project in the same time.

Comment: I figured that much. Thus my advice. While learning, stay away from mutability.

Comment: Some people are more Roman than the Pope - sometimes you need mutability

Comment: @thebluephantom Sometimes you do ... But not before you are familiar with the language enough to correctly recognize those cases.